# Stopping a rogue PHP script sending E-Mail

Tags: php, web, kill, terminate

Please don't laugh at me but I believe that I just did something extremely stupid. I was working on setting up a newsletter for a site that I am working on, but I tried it out at first when there was a typo. While scanning throughout the database and sending emails, I screwed up on the part that makes it stop. I fixed the code, but the emails are still being send (to my mom :O) and they don't seem to be stoping.

This is the script when I executed it:

```
$message = $_POST['emailmessage'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `email` FROM `members` WHERE `active`='1'");
//This line underneath should not be there
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$headers = array(
    "From: contact@thestopitcampaign.com",
    "Content-Type: text/html"
);
//should be '$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)' instead of '$rows'
while($rows)
{
    mail($rows['email'],$subject,$message,implode("\r\n",$headers));
    echo "<p>Sent to: " . $rows['email'] . "</p>";
}
```

I contacted FatCow to see if they could stop the script, but they said that they could not do that and they would have to delete my entire account and put me on a different server. I cannot do that. Is there anyway to generate an error or something that would make the rogue script stop? FYI I do not have SSH access.

--I looked in my php config file and the timeout for a script is 300 seconds. That seems like a lot of emails to send. Is there anyway to stop those emails?

Comment: FatCow does not give its clients SSH access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What has been sent can't be stopped any more. But it won't run forever and probably has already stopped.

If the server is not grossly misconfigured by the provider, your script didn't run any longer than a certain time limit, e.g. 60 seconds. Even though messages continue to come through, it's probably no longer running, but the mail server is taking its time to handle all the messages that it created.

I would wait and see - the flood is likely to end soon.

What the provider says about moving the account to a different server doesn't seem to make any sense at all - if there is a rogue process that is sending E-Mail, they should be able to kill it easily. But anyway... I would wait.

Comment: Yeah I think I will have to wait, just the script was running for 300 seconds according to the config file, so that will be a lot of emails.

Comment: @Keiran yeah, that might be quite a batch. Nothing to do but wait it out though... (except of course, if your mum is using a desktop E-Mail client, set up a filter rule to auto-delete the incoming mails so she doesn't drown in them :)

Comment: Yeah I already have a rule to filter them out and delete them, just it goes to her trash, so they are still there pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the emails are just queued up and should eventually stop as php script wont keep executing itself after the page has stopped loading.

I'd suggest you to use a newsletter provider like [mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/) as they are more relyable, are safe and the service is easy to integrate in your website.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The maximum time for a script to run is 300 seconds on the server. Isn't that a long time? I think the emails will probably go a while. With mail chimp, is it possible to get email addresses of my members from a mysql database and use that?

Comment: Do you mean, wether it's possible to import them from your database?

If so you can probably generate an xml, csv or an excel file to import into mailchimp. But you cannot feed the emails from your database to mailchimp dinamically as far as I know. You should then probably go with your own solution.